# glTranslatef does not work

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

In my project I want to render rain, so I use particles.

My render method:

```
public void draw(Camera camera) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);     
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(camera.getX(), camera.getEyeLevel(), camera.getY());

    glColor4f(0, 0, 0.8f, 0.1f);

    for(int i = 0; i < _currentParticlesCount; i++)
    {
        _particles[i].draw();
    }

    glPopMatrix();
    glEnd();
}
```

Rain particle init method:

```
particle.setX(Utils.RANDOM.nextFloat() * RAIN_RADIUS * (Utils.RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1));
particle.setY(Utils.RANDOM.nextFloat() * RAIN_RADIUS);
particle.setZ(Utils.RANDOM.nextFloat() * RAIN_RADIUS * (Utils.RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1));
```

You see that I want to translate all the particles to the camera's place - relative to player.
But there is one problem, glTranslatef simply does n't work.
So I see all the particles in the beginning of the world's coordinate system.

In fact, when I draw stars (particles) using the same principle, glTranslatef works properly.

Stars render method:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glPushMatrix();     
glTranslatef(camera.getX(), camera.getEyeLevel(), camera.getY());

glBegin(GL_POINTS);

glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

for(int i = 0; i < STARS_COUNT; i++) {
    _starsArray[i].draw();
}

glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

What am I doing wrong?

P. S. I use OpenGL 1.1 LWJGL, Java OpenGL wrapper (lwjgl.org)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

glTranslatef won't work because it's between [glBegin](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml)/glEnd.

You can use glGetError() ([eg](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html)) to make finding bugs like this easier.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my problem. But in fact, in other place of my program, I use glTranslaref to draw polygons between glBegin/glEnd and there glTranslatef works properly. Is there any differenses between drawing points and drawing polygons? What are the situations where I should use glTranslatef before glBegin?

Comment: glTranslatef shouldn't work between begin/end (although the driver may let you, it's not supported in the [specs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml)). Calling glBegin tells opengl you're going to start drawing something and until glEnd you should generally only be setting vertex attributes and calling glVertex*. This allows the opengl implementation to better parallelise rendering as it knows updates to the state, such as the modelview matrix, won't occur and interrupt the stream of vertices (this is my guess anyway). I'd suggest looking into VBOs as soon as possible.